# Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) error in Joomla 3.0 PHP with parent::display(); in controller

Tags: php, google-chrome, iis-7, joomla, joomla3.0

In a custom component controller in Joomla 3.0 I receive the following error

`Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)`

in response to visiting `/administrator/index.php?option=com_customname`

commenting out the `parent::display();` in the /customname/controller.php
the page displays but obviously is missing key information / options / form.

hard refresh and clearing of cache doesn't fix the issue, it is not just chrome specific either FF and IE also return a blank page.

any ideas?

thanks in advance

**Edit 1**

- Error logging on... nothing being recorded.
- site is for development on localhost.
- Win7 with IIS7.

**Edit 2**

trying to access: administrator/index.php?option=com_custonname&view=customnametypo

`An error has occurred.
500 View not found [name, type, prefix]: customnametypo, html, custonameView`

Comment: Turn on PHP error logging, set verbosity to the highest level and track the error log. Do the same with the error log of your webserver. The error you describe can have many reasons, some of them are client/server related. So some more information can be helpful if you like to troubleshoot your issue. For example the full error message from chrome.

Comment: Error logging on... nothing being recorded.

Comment: Not to state the obvious, but have you restarted chrome and the webserver?

Comment: i have, the problem isn't every page though, a typo in the component name returns a 404 as expected. only when trying to the component or a view does the error appear.

Comment: So your url 
 /administrator/index.php?option=com_customname
Does not have a view which is probably why it is complaining about not having a view. 
Probably two things should happen ... first consider using a view.
Second add a fall back view for when no view is specified. Usually in the administrator that would be the "manager" view that extends adminList

Comment: it complains about not having a view if i make a typo in the name, as in, obviously, not a view that exists, when i do specify the correctly named view i get the above error. The view does exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is and incorrect coding in select query compared to the database column headings created by the insert script within the component installation.

It isn't handled gracefully by Joomla and throws the above mentioned error, rather than a useful 500 and error log / debug information

Comment: will leave the Google Chrome tag in place, although not related to this issue, the error message seems to appear related to Chrome a lot in Google searches and this answer might be the solution for others, or indicative of a coding error over a browser issue.